# C++ fixed-size vector backed by custom buffer

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Is there any STL container that implements a fixed-size vector *backed by a custom buffer* and allows me do to something like:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 5, 12, 34, 12, 56, 12};
std::mysteryvector<int> vec(arr + 2, 3); // <-- No copy here, and 3 can be a variable
                                         // (no compile-time template parameter)
std::cout << *vec.begin() << std::endl; // prints 5
std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl; // prints 3
// There is no push_back() or resize(), but size(), begin(), end(), etc. 
// work as in std::vector
arr[4] = 1212;
std::cout << vec[2] << std::endl; // prints 1212
```

Or should I implement it myself? Are hacks/workarounds like using a custom allocator for `std::vector` recommended?

EDIT. **Why**? Compatibility with legacy code that assumes the existence of `size()`, `begin()`, `end()`, `[]` but does not call `push_back()`.

Comment: There's is no such thing, standard containers make copies of elements and that's that.

Comment: Why do you need something other than the array (or `std::array`)?

Comment: @Chad: I have existing code that relies on .begin(), .end(), .size() but does not push_back(). For efficiency I have to avoid copies, so a custom-buffer backed vector that implements 80% of std::vector would be very helpful.

Comment: Something like this? http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1MutableArrayRef.html

Comment: I suppose a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>` could probably technically work.

Comment: @gd1, Do you know your size at compile time (as in the example)?  If so, you _want_ `std::array`.  If `c++11` isn't available, it's trivial to provide a simple replacement.

Comment: @Chad: No I don't. The test code I've written for this hypothetical container should run even if "3" is replaced with a variable :)

Comment: Is the maximum size of your "fixed size storage" set at compile time?  If not, just use `std::vector`, or a custom class (implemented in terms of `std::vector` that disallows copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want something with `begin`, `end`, `size`, and `[]`?  Would something like this work?

```
class FakeVector{
    int* m_begin;
    int* m_end;
    size_t m_size;
  public:
    FakeVector(int* begin, size_t size)
      : m_begin(begin), m_end(begin + size), m_size(size) { }

    int* begin()  { return m_begin; }
    int* end()    { return m_end; }
    size_t size() { return m_size; }
    int& operator[] (size_t index) { return m_begin[index]; }

    // And, in case you need const access:
    const int* begin() const { return m_begin; }
    const int* end()   const { return m_end; }
    const int& operator[] (size_t index) const { return m_begin[index]; }
  };


  int arr[] = {1, 2, 5, 12, 34, 12, 56, 12};
  FakeVector vec(arr + 2, 3);
  std::cout << *vec.begin() << std::endl;  // prints 5
  std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl; // prints 3
  arr[4] = 1212;
  std::cout << vec[2] << std::endl; // prints 1212
```

That's hard-coded to `int` right now, but that should be fairly simple to templatize.

Comment: +1 Believe it or not, while you were posting this answer I was already writing something like this. It is templatized and I have also added typedefs for `iterator` and `const_iterator`. It seems I've fooled the legacy code (doing tests right now).

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing, unfortunately.

However, there's a proposal for string_ref and array_ref at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3334.html.

Boost appears to already have implemented string_ref, you can check here: http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::array<int, 3>* mymistvector = new (arr + 2) std::array<int, 3>();
```

Comment: Nice hack but the size of the vector is known at runtime.

Comment: auto size = mymistvector->size();

Comment: This is not what I meant.

Comment: Do you want to determine it's size in runtime?

Comment: I want to _define_ its size at runtime.

Comment: This approach does not make the allocated array to *use* the storage offered by the buffer (arr+2), rather, the array object itself (including a pointer, and size field) uses the buffer, the actual content that the pointer refers to is still allocated from heap.

Comment: @X.J: You're confusing `std::array` with `std::vector`.  `std::array` does no heap allocation, and has no pointer member or size field member.  Its only data member is a native array.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fixed size vector class called fector that acts like a std::vector but has a templated size like std::array. You can find it [here](https://github.com/burner/sweet.hpp/blob/master/fector.hpp). It is a self contained header with 150 LOC

```
sweet::fector<int,128> f;
for(int i = 0; i < 128; ++i) {
    f.push_back(i);
}

// the next push_back will throw
```